# How to write text inside created rectangle on canvas using fabric.js canvas library

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Is it possible to write text on created rectangle on HTML5 canvas? and also move text when we move rectangle.

Comment: you would need to draw the box and then the text as two separate components. You would then need to redraw the text relative to the box upon each move. Using CSS and actual elements would be easier for this sort of thing.

Comment: it is possible. you need to use below canvas properties:
  context.fillStyle = 'color-name';
  context.fillText(`your-text-goes-here`, Xpixel, Ypixel);
for example:
      context.fillStyle = 'black';
      context.fillText(`some Text`, 200, 80);

Answer (score 4):

### Avoid layering HTML over an animated canvas

Both the existing answers suggest that you use HTML and add the text over the canvas.

This may be easier in terms of code but be warned that text over a canvas that contains animated or changing content will need the overlaying text to be rendered (composited) even if you only change a single pixel on the canvas or there is a re-flow on the page.

Having several items over the canvas and changing any of these items can under some coding styles forces all the items to be re-composited with the under laying canvas element.

Always use `requestAnimationFrame` if you are changing content regularly (or realtime) to avoid unneeded compositing of page content.

### Box text complications?

As you have not given context regarding the text, the size, the number of boxes, if it is to be animated (real-time or sub real-time), are there any transformations, are you using gradients, patterns, filters, composite operations, or shadows. All of which will require differing techniques to get the best results in terms of quality and performance.

### Simple Box Text

At the most basic. A text box with the text centered can be done with a simple function.

The arguments all have defaults and you need only pass an object setting the arguments you want to change.

```js
const myTextBox = {text: "Hi World!!", x: 100, y: 20, background: "#08F8"};
boxText(myTextBox);

function boxText({
        c = ctx, 
        text, x, y, 
        font = "arial", 
        size = 32, 
        padding = 4, 
        color = "#FFF", 
        boxStyle = "#000", 
        background = "", 
        lineWidth = 2
    }) {    
    c.font = size + "px " + font;
    c.textAlign = "center";
    c.textBaseline = "middle";
    const width = c.measureText(text).width;
    if (background) {
        c.fillStyle = background;
        c.fillRect(x, y, width + padding * 2, size + padding * 2);
    }
    if (boxStyle) {
        c.strokeStyle = boxStyle;
        c.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        c.strokeRect(
            x - lineWidth / 2, y - lineWidth / 2,
            width + padding * 2 + lineWidth, size + padding * 2 + lineWidth
        );
    }
    c.fillStyle = color;
    c.fillText(text, x + width / 2 +  padding, y + padding + size / 2 + size / 16);
}
```

Note that in this code I move the text down a little, you may not want to do this so just change the last line to `c.fillText(text, x + width / 2 +  padding, y + padding + size / 2);`

### Demo

Using the above function in animated example.

```js
requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const textA = {text: "Hi World!!", x: 100, y: 20, background: "#08F8"};
const textB = {text: "Example 2", x: 100, y: 80, size: 26, color: "black", background: "#F808"};

function renderLoop(time) {
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
   textA.x = Math.sin(time / 2500) * 150 + 160;
   textB.x = Math.cos(time / 2500) * 150 + 160;
   textB.text = "Time: " + (time / 1000).toFixed(3);
   boxText(textA);
   boxText(textB);
   requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
}


function boxText({
        c = ctx, text, x, y, 
        font = "arial", size = 32, color = "#FFF",
        padding = 4, background = "", 
        boxStyle = "#000", lineWidth = 2
    }) {    
    c.font = size + "px " + font;
    c.textAlign = "center";
    c.textBaseline = "middle";
    const width = c.measureText(text).width;
    if (background) {
        c.fillStyle = background;
        c.fillRect(x, y, width + padding * 2, size + padding * 2);
    }
    if (boxStyle) {
        c.strokeStyle = boxStyle;
        c.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        c.strokeRect(
            x - lineWidth / 2, y - lineWidth / 2,
            width + padding * 2 + lineWidth, size + padding * 2 + lineWidth
        );
    }
    c.fillStyle = color;
    c.fillText(text, x + width / 2 +  padding, y + padding + size / 2 + size / 16);
}
```

```html
<canvas id = "canvas" width=500 height=150></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a class called `TextBox` which performs the logic of grouping text using `.fillText()` and a box `.fillRect()`. The class keeps track of the text to draw as well as the background colour and colour of the text itself. Each draw then draws the box and the text for you. You can then move the box by altering the boxes `x` and `y` properties.

See example below:

```js
const canavs = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

class TextBox {
  constructor(text, x, y, bgColor="black", textColor="white") {
    this.text = text;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.bgColor = bgColor;
    this.textColor = textColor;
  }
  draw() {
    const text_info = ctx.measureText(this.text);
    const height = ctx.font.match(/\d+/).pop() || 10;
    const width = text_info.width;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.bgColor;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, width, height);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.textColor;
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
  }
}

const textBox = new TextBox("Hello", 10, 10, "black", "white");
ctx.font = "30pt Arial"; // use pt instead of px (need for height calc)

setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  textBox.x++;
  textBox.draw();
}, 1000/60);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
```

As you can see, using the canvas for this is a little finicky, I would much prefer using HTML + CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are two ways:

A) Draw text on the canvas itself, there is an example at w3schools (I often avoid that site but that example seems fine), at https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_text.asp

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Hello World", 10, 50);
```

That draws the text to the canvas, a 2D bitmap, as an image .. so you can't copy-paste it.

B) Use HTML and CSS to overlay normal HTML text over the Canvas. I think that's best done by making a DIV to be a container and then putting both the Canvas and your text HTML element(s) in it. This way the text on the page is as text, copy-paste works. Also, unlike what the comment to your question says, I think you can then move the container DIV around and the text stays automatically over the canvas and there is no need to redraw it or anything.